# SQL Rolling Count in Time Series

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table of companies and how many news articles was written about each company each day for 10 years (and about 3000 companies). I want to do a "rolling" count where for each company, I count the number of total news articles in a 3-day window, conditional on there being a positive number of news articles. For example, starting on day 1, if the number of articles is 0, skip and go to day 2, etc until we hit a day (say day 4) where there is 1 article, and then count the total number of articles in the next 3 days (so days 4,5,6). After that, I go to day 7 and keep scanning until I find the first day that has a news article, and repeat this 3-day sum, and keep scanning after that, etc. I will repeat this for each company.

I've thought of doing a rolling sum using window functions but with 3000 companies times 365*10 days of data rolling sum may computationally take too long, and plus I wouldn't need the sums to be computed on days that I skip over (so either days with 0 or days that are not the first days in the 3-day interval).

For example, the time series for each company may be (Day #:Number of Articles)

```
Day 1:0
Day 2:0
Day 3:0
Day 4:1
Day 5:3
Day 6:2
Day 7:0
Day 8:0
Day 9:20
Day 10:2
Day 11:0
```

Then the output would be

```
Day 4:6 (1 from Day 4, 3 from Day 5, and 2 from Day 6)
Day 9:22 (20 from day 9, 2 from day 10, 0 from day 11).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the more recent versions of SQLite, you would use `row_number()`:

```
select company, min(date), max(date), sum(num_articles)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by company order by date) as seqnum
      from t
      where num_articles > 0
     ) t
group by company, floor((seqnum - 1) / 3);
```

Comment: I think you need a few modifications or I am reading it wrong. I think you want to exclude 0s from subquery and I think you are looking for integer division instead of mod so that seqnum 1,2,3 are grouped into 0 and 4,5,6 are grouped into 1 and so on.

Comment: @KeithL . . . Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem... I saw where you were going with it. No need for 2 answers.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost exactly what I needed. Per @KeithL's suggestion, I changed it to num_articles > 0. One remaining issue is that if there is a 0 within the range of 3 days, it skips over the 0 and adds the subsequent non-zero days, which isn't exactly what I need. For example, if the counts by date (starting at day 1) are 0,10,0,7,7,1,0,0,1 then the code gives me 24 for day 2 (10+7+7) and 9 for day 6 (7+1+1), where ideally I would want 17 for day 2 (10+0+7) and 8 for day 5 (7+1+0) and 1 for day 9?